# FireMonkey app tethering not working on wifi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I've written a desktop app in Delphi 10.4 community edition (FMX app) and an Android app to share photos from an Android phone to a windows desktop app. Both are working perfectly when the laptop with the Windows app is connected to the local network with a cable, but not when I'm using Wifi. Phone and laptop are on the same subnet. Anybody had the same issue but having a solution for this?
Tried to connect with the windows firewall for private network off. Both phone and laptop are on the same Wifi network. When the laptop is connected to LAN everything is working as expected. I'm using on both apps TTetheringManager and TTetheringProfile.

Comment: Since you haven't provided enough information I have to be just guessing. But based on your description I would guess that your Desktop application might be listening for incoming network traffic only on your LAN network card and not on your Wireless network card. SO check configuration of your networking components to make sure you are not limiting yourself to only one specific network card. With Indy components you control this with **Binding** property.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thanks for the answer. I'm using TTetheringManager and TTetheringAppProfile. TTetheringManager has a property AllowedAdapters which is set on Network. Other possibilities there are Network_V4 and Network_V6 and BlueTooth. I know that for the BT connection it is mandatory to connect to a named device where on Network you can simply retrieve a list of active TetheringManagers to select from. And that's the way I want to go, but if possible also over Wifi. See also articles about App Tethering by Malcolm Groves [link](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1854)